Visual Studio unable to launch the installer. Error: the system cannot find the file specified

I removed Visual Studio 2022 Community and tried to reinstall it.
Every time I get this error.
I tried everything I found on the internet: removing all the "leftovers", cleaning the registry, downloading the bootstrapper, etc.

I encountered the same issue, and the solution for me was to do the same as the poster's comment, but I thought I would add a more detailed explanation.
Find where the Visual Studio installer is located in your program files. For me, this was in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio.
Within that directory, rename or delete the folder called "Installer" then rerun whichever Visual Studio setup application you need from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
This got rid of the error for me and allowed me to properly install VS.

For this Visual Studio setup issue, here are suggestions you can check:
1.Please try to download a new  VS Installer from Microsoft web page an run as an administrator to launch the Installer.
2.Please try to run SFC scanning on your machine.The sfc /scannow command will scan all protected system files, and replace corrupted files with a cached copy that is located in a compressed folder at %WinDir%\System32\dllcache.
sfc /scannow

After scanning and correcting errors, restart the computer and re-run your Installer to see if the issue persists.
3.Please check if you have specialized anti-virus, app-blocker, or GPO phased permission software installed that maybe be blocking this installation. If so, please temporarily disable it.
In addition, if your issue persists, you can collect setup log files generated during installation and check the error messages in dd_installer_xxx/dd_setup_xxx files or share the error messages.
1 download Microsoft Visual Studio and .NET Framework log collection tool
https://aka.ms/vscollect
2 run Collect.exe in an administrative command prompt The tool generates a vslogs.zip file in your %TEMP% folder, typically at C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Temp\vslogs.zip.
For more information, please refer to:Troubleshoot installation or upgrades - Visual Studio (Windows)
Hope it can help you.

It turned out the solution to this problem is simpler than expected. All I needed to do is renaming the folder that contains the visual studio installer, and it worked like a charm!

If you want to find the root cause of the issue, you can check your installation log files as mentioned above. As you have found a workaround to resolve this installation issue, you can share your method  that could help other community members who get the same issues issue to find the solution easily.
